# Optimising the Selection of MaxValue in Association

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, maximum

Suppose I have the following Association:

```
f=<|"vanilla:veal" -> (353.073 x + 1137.02 x^2 + 2301.78 x^3 + 
     3771.09 x^4 + 5369.78 x^5 + 6302.43 x^6 + 6703.86 x^7 + 
     6518.57 x^8 + 5440.72 x^9 + 4612.02 x^10 + 3457.49 x^11 + 
     2654.9 x^12 + 2100.02 x^13 + 1521.13 x^14 + 1076.02 x^15 + 
     755.953 x^16 + 480.615 x^17 + 261.089 x^18 + 204.306 x^19 + 
     110.874 x^20 + 55.7565 x^21 + 28.2723 x^22 + 28.1937 x^23 + 
     19.6806 x^24 + 5.60733 x^25 + 3.72775 x^26 + 0.929319 x^27 + 
     1.8534 x^28 + 2.77225 x^29 + 0.921466 x^30 + 
     1.8377 x^31)/(354 x + 1143 x^2 + 2320 x^3 + 3811 x^4 + 
     5441 x^5 + 6403 x^6 + 6829 x^7 + 6658 x^8 + 5571 x^9 + 
     4737 x^10 + 3560 x^11 + 2741 x^12 + 2174 x^13 + 1579 x^14 + 
     1120 x^15 + 789 x^16 + 502 x^17 + 275 x^18 + 215 x^19 + 
     117 x^20 + 59 x^21 + 30 x^22 + 30 x^23 + 21 x^24 + 6 x^25 + 
     4 x^26 + x^27 + 2 x^28 + 3 x^29 + x^30 + 2 x^31), 
 "leek:white_wine" -> (353.073 x + 1137.02 x^2 + 2301.78 x^3 + 
     3772.08 x^4 + 5369.78 x^5 + 6306.37 x^6 + 6699.93 x^7 + 
     6523.46 x^8 + 5443.65 x^9 + 4606.18 x^10 + 3463.31 x^11 + 
     2651.02 x^12 + 2101.95 x^13 + 1520.17 x^14 + 1073.14 x^15 + 
     755.953 x^16 + 476.793 x^17 + 264.901 x^18 + 202.406 x^19 + 
     111.822 x^20 + 53.8665 x^21 + 29.2147 x^22 + 27.2539 x^23 + 
     19.6806 x^24 + 5.60733 x^25 + 3.72775 x^26 + 0.929319 x^27 + 
     1.8534 x^28 + 2.77225 x^29 + 0.921466 x^30 + 
     1.8377 x^31)/(354 x + 1143 x^2 + 2320 x^3 + 3811 x^4 + 
     5441 x^5 + 6403 x^6 + 6829 x^7 + 6658 x^8 + 5571 x^9 + 
     4737 x^10 + 3560 x^11 + 2741 x^12 + 2174 x^13 + 1579 x^14 + 
     1120 x^15 + 789 x^16 + 502 x^17 + 275 x^18 + 215 x^19 + 
     117 x^20 + 59 x^21 + 30 x^22 + 30 x^23 + 21 x^24 + 6 x^25 + 
     4 x^26 + x^27 + 2 x^28 + 3 x^29 + x^30 + 2 x^31), 
 "orange:shiitake" -> (353.073 x + 1137.02 x^2 + 2301.78 x^3 + 
     3771.09 x^4 + 5369.78 x^5 + 6302.43 x^6 + 6703.86 x^7 + 
     6518.57 x^8 + 5440.72 x^9 + 4612.02 x^10 + 3457.49 x^11 + 
     2655.86 x^12 + 2099.05 x^13 + 1521.13 x^14 + 1076.02 x^15 + 
     755.953 x^16 + 479.66 x^17 + 262.995 x^18 + 203.356 x^19 + 
     110.874 x^20 + 55.7565 x^21 + 28.2723 x^22 + 28.1937 x^23 + 
     19.6806 x^24 + 5.60733 x^25 + 3.72775 x^26 + 0.929319 x^27 + 
     1.8534 x^28 + 2.77225 x^29 + 0.921466 x^30 + 
     1.8377 x^31)/(354 x + 1143 x^2 + 2320 x^3 + 3811 x^4 + 
     5441 x^5 + 6403 x^6 + 6829 x^7 + 6658 x^8 + 5571 x^9 + 
     4737 x^10 + 3560 x^11 + 2741 x^12 + 2174 x^13 + 1579 x^14 + 
     1120 x^15 + 789 x^16 + 502 x^17 + 275 x^18 + 215 x^19 + 
     117 x^20 + 59 x^21 + 30 x^22 + 30 x^23 + 21 x^24 + 6 x^25 + 
     4 x^26 + x^27 + 2 x^28 + 3 x^29 + x^30 + 2 x^31), 
 "pepper:smoked_sausage" -> (353.073 x + 1137.02 x^2 + 2301.78 x^3 + 
     3773.07 x^4 + 5370.77 x^5 + 6303.41 x^6 + 6708.77 x^7 + 
     6522.48 x^8 + 5432.91 x^9 + 4612.02 x^10 + 3461.37 x^11 + 
     2650.05 x^12 + 2100.02 x^13 + 1520.17 x^14 + 1075.06 x^15 + 
     754.037 x^16 + 481.571 x^17 + 262.042 x^18 + 203.356 x^19 + 
     109.927 x^20 + 55.7565 x^21 + 28.2723 x^22 + 28.1937 x^23 + 
     19.6806 x^24 + 5.60733 x^25 + 3.72775 x^26 + 0.929319 x^27 + 
     1.8534 x^28 + 2.77225 x^29 + 0.921466 x^30 + 
     1.8377 x^31)/(354 x + 1143 x^2 + 2320 x^3 + 3811 x^4 + 
     5441 x^5 + 6403 x^6 + 6829 x^7 + 6658 x^8 + 5571 x^9 + 
     4737 x^10 + 3560 x^11 + 2741 x^12 + 2174 x^13 + 1579 x^14 + 
     1120 x^15 + 789 x^16 + 502 x^17 + 275 x^18 + 215 x^19 + 
     117 x^20 + 59 x^21 + 30 x^22 + 30 x^23 + 21 x^24 + 6 x^25 + 
     4 x^26 + x^27 + 2 x^28 + 3 x^29 + x^30 + 2 x^31), 
 "carrot:celery" -> (353.073 x + 1137.02 x^2 + 2301.78 x^3 + 
     3787.92 x^4 + 5375.7 x^5 + 6322.12 x^6 + 6740.18 x^7 + 
     6545.98 x^8 + 5464.16 x^9 + 4600.34 x^10 + 3451.66 x^11 + 
     2659.74 x^12 + 2084.56 x^13 + 1512.46 x^14 + 1049.12 x^15 + 
     733.916 x^16 + 467.238 x^17 + 254.419 x^18 + 199.555 x^19 + 
     107.084 x^20 + 47.2513 x^21 + 31.0995 x^22 + 23.4948 x^23 + 
     18.7435 x^24 + 5.60733 x^25 + 3.72775 x^26 + 0.929319 x^27 + 
     0.926702 x^28 + 2.77225 x^29 + 1.84293 x^30 + 
     0.918848 x^31)/(354 x + 1143 x^2 + 2320 x^3 + 3811 x^4 + 
     5441 x^5 + 6403 x^6 + 6829 x^7 + 6658 x^8 + 5571 x^9 + 
     4737 x^10 + 3560 x^11 + 2741 x^12 + 2174 x^13 + 1579 x^14 + 
     1120 x^15 + 789 x^16 + 502 x^17 + 275 x^18 + 215 x^19 + 
     117 x^20 + 59 x^21 + 30 x^22 + 30 x^23 + 21 x^24 + 6 x^25 + 
     4 x^26 + x^27 + 2 x^28 + 3 x^29 + x^30 + 2 x^31), 
 "cane_molasses:cumin" -> (353.073 x + 1137.02 x^2 + 2303.76 x^3 + 
     3769.12 x^4 + 5371.76 x^5 + 6304.4 x^6 + 6706.81 x^7 + 
     6518.57 x^8 + 5447.56 x^9 + 4618.84 x^10 + 3458.46 x^11 + 
     2655.86 x^12 + 2105.81 x^13 + 1514.39 x^14 + 1076.98 x^15 + 
     749.246 x^16 + 479.66 x^17 + 255.372 x^18 + 208.107 x^19 + 
     108.031 x^20 + 51.9764 x^21 + 24.5026 x^22 + 28.1937 x^23 + 
     18.7435 x^24 + 5.60733 x^25 + 2.79581 x^26 + 0.929319 x^27 + 
     2.7801 x^28 + 2.77225 x^29 + 1.8377 x^31)/(354 x + 1143 x^2 + 
     2320 x^3 + 3811 x^4 + 5441 x^5 + 6403 x^6 + 6829 x^7 + 
     6658 x^8 + 5571 x^9 + 4737 x^10 + 3560 x^11 + 2741 x^12 + 
     2174 x^13 + 1579 x^14 + 1120 x^15 + 789 x^16 + 502 x^17 + 
     275 x^18 + 215 x^19 + 117 x^20 + 59 x^21 + 30 x^22 + 30 x^23 + 
     21 x^24 + 6 x^25 + 4 x^26 + x^27 + 2 x^28 + 3 x^29 + x^30 + 
     2 x^31), 
 "lettuce:turnip" -> (353.073 x + 1137.02 x^2 + 2301.78 x^3 + 
     3771.09 x^4 + 5369.78 x^5 + 6302.43 x^6 + 6703.86 x^7 + 
     6519.54 x^8 + 5438.77 x^9 + 4612.99 x^10 + 3457.49 x^11 + 
     2654.9 x^12 + 2100.02 x^13 + 1521.13 x^14 + 1076.02 x^15 + 
     755.953 x^16 + 479.66 x^17 + 262.042 x^18 + 204.306 x^19 + 
     110.874 x^20 + 55.7565 x^21 + 28.2723 x^22 + 28.1937 x^23 + 
     19.6806 x^24 + 5.60733 x^25 + 3.72775 x^26 + 0.929319 x^27 + 
     1.8534 x^28 + 2.77225 x^29 + 0.921466 x^30 + 
     1.8377 x^31)/(354 x + 1143 x^2 + 2320 x^3 + 3811 x^4 + 
     5441 x^5 + 6403 x^6 + 6829 x^7 + 6658 x^8 + 5571 x^9 + 
     4737 x^10 + 3560 x^11 + 2741 x^12 + 2174 x^13 + 1579 x^14 + 
     1120 x^15 + 789 x^16 + 502 x^17 + 275 x^18 + 215 x^19 + 
     117 x^20 + 59 x^21 + 30 x^22 + 30 x^23 + 21 x^24 + 6 x^25 + 
     4 x^26 + x^27 + 2 x^28 + 3 x^29 + x^30 + 2 x^31), 
 "corn_grit:pork_sausage" -> (353.073 x + 1137.02 x^2 + 2302.77 x^3 + 
     3771.09 x^4 + 5371.76 x^5 + 6301.45 x^6 + 6701.9 x^7 + 
     6519.54 x^8 + 5439.75 x^9 + 4612.99 x^10 + 3457.49 x^11 + 
     2654.9 x^12 + 2100.98 x^13 + 1519.2 x^14 + 1076.02 x^15 + 
     755.953 x^16 + 479.66 x^17 + 262.042 x^18 + 204.306 x^19 + 
     110.874 x^20 + 55.7565 x^21 + 28.2723 x^22 + 28.1937 x^23 + 
     19.6806 x^24 + 5.60733 x^25 + 3.72775 x^26 + 0.929319 x^27 + 
     2.7801 x^28 + 1.84817 x^29 + 0.921466 x^30 + 
     1.8377 x^31)/(354 x + 1143 x^2 + 2320 x^3 + 3811 x^4 + 
     5441 x^5 + 6403 x^6 + 6829 x^7 + 6658 x^8 + 5571 x^9 + 
     4737 x^10 + 3560 x^11 + 2741 x^12 + 2174 x^13 + 1579 x^14 + 
     1120 x^15 + 789 x^16 + 502 x^17 + 275 x^18 + 215 x^19 + 
     117 x^20 + 59 x^21 + 30 x^22 + 30 x^23 + 21 x^24 + 6 x^25 + 
     4 x^26 + x^27 + 2 x^28 + 3 x^29 + x^30 + 2 x^31), 
 "avocado:pumpkin" -> (353.073 x + 1137.02 x^2 + 2301.78 x^3 + 
     3771.09 x^4 + 5369.78 x^5 + 6303.41 x^6 + 6702.88 x^7 + 
     6518.57 x^8 + 5440.72 x^9 + 4612.02 x^10 + 3457.49 x^11 + 
     2654.9 x^12 + 2100.02 x^13 + 1521.13 x^14 + 1076.02 x^15 + 
     755.953 x^16 + 479.66 x^17 + 262.042 x^18 + 204.306 x^19 + 
     110.874 x^20 + 55.7565 x^21 + 28.2723 x^22 + 28.1937 x^23 + 
     19.6806 x^24 + 5.60733 x^25 + 3.72775 x^26 + 0.929319 x^27 + 
     1.8534 x^28 + 2.77225 x^29 + 0.921466 x^30 + 
     1.8377 x^31)/(354 x + 1143 x^2 + 2320 x^3 + 3811 x^4 + 
     5441 x^5 + 6403 x^6 + 6829 x^7 + 6658 x^8 + 5571 x^9 + 
     4737 x^10 + 3560 x^11 + 2741 x^12 + 2174 x^13 + 1579 x^14 + 
     1120 x^15 + 789 x^16 + 502 x^17 + 275 x^18 + 215 x^19 + 
     117 x^20 + 59 x^21 + 30 x^22 + 30 x^23 + 21 x^24 + 6 x^25 + 
     4 x^26 + x^27 + 2 x^28 + 3 x^29 + x^30 + 2 x^31), 
 "chive:mandarin_peel" -> (353.073 x + 1137.02 x^2 + 2301.78 x^3 + 
     3771.09 x^4 + 5369.78 x^5 + 6302.43 x^6 + 6704.84 x^7 + 
     6517.59 x^8 + 5439.75 x^9 + 4612.99 x^10 + 3457.49 x^11 + 
     2654.9 x^12 + 2100.02 x^13 + 1521.13 x^14 + 1076.02 x^15 + 
     755.953 x^16 + 479.66 x^17 + 262.042 x^18 + 204.306 x^19 + 
     110.874 x^20 + 55.7565 x^21 + 28.2723 x^22 + 28.1937 x^23 + 
     19.6806 x^24 + 5.60733 x^25 + 3.72775 x^26 + 0.929319 x^27 + 
     1.8534 x^28 + 2.77225 x^29 + 0.921466 x^30 + 
     1.8377 x^31)/(354 x + 1143 x^2 + 2320 x^3 + 3811 x^4 + 
     5441 x^5 + 6403 x^6 + 6829 x^7 + 6658 x^8 + 5571 x^9 + 
     4737 x^10 + 3560 x^11 + 2741 x^12 + 2174 x^13 + 1579 x^14 + 
     1120 x^15 + 789 x^16 + 502 x^17 + 275 x^18 + 215 x^19 + 
     117 x^20 + 59 x^21 + 30 x^22 + 30 x^23 + 21 x^24 + 6 x^25 + 
     4 x^26 + x^27 + 2 x^28 + 3 x^29 + x^30 + 2 x^31), 
 "anise_seed:coconut" -> (353.073 x + 1137.02 x^2 + 2301.78 x^3 + 
     3771.09 x^4 + 5369.78 x^5 + 6302.43 x^6 + 6703.86 x^7 + 
     6518.57 x^8 + 5439.75 x^9 + 4612.99 x^10 + 3457.49 x^11 + 
     2654.9 x^12 + 2100.98 x^13 + 1521.13 x^14 + 1075.06 x^15 + 
     755.953 x^16 + 479.66 x^17 + 262.042 x^18 + 204.306 x^19 + 
     110.874 x^20 + 55.7565 x^21 + 28.2723 x^22 + 28.1937 x^23 + 
     19.6806 x^24 + 5.60733 x^25 + 3.72775 x^26 + 0.929319 x^27 + 
     1.8534 x^28 + 2.77225 x^29 + 0.921466 x^30 + 
     1.8377 x^31)/(354 x + 1143 x^2 + 2320 x^3 + 3811 x^4 + 
     5441 x^5 + 6403 x^6 + 6829 x^7 + 6658 x^8 + 5571 x^9 + 
     4737 x^10 + 3560 x^11 + 2741 x^12 + 2174 x^13 + 1579 x^14 + 
     1120 x^15 + 789 x^16 + 502 x^17 + 275 x^18 + 215 x^19 + 
     117 x^20 + 59 x^21 + 30 x^22 + 30 x^23 + 21 x^24 + 6 x^25 + 
     4 x^26 + x^27 + 2 x^28 + 3 x^29 + x^30 + 2 x^31)|>
```

which contains rational functions. I want to select the ones that have y value above 1 for a specific range of x, so I do:

```
Select[f, MaxValue[{#, 2/382 <= x <= 1}, x] > 1 &] // AbsoluteTiming
```

in this case none of them are, so I get:

```
{1.80393, <||>}
```

The point is that my original list contains 30000 of these polynomials and the command I have for selection is taking a lot of time. For 10 of them as above it took 1.8 seconds. I wonder how can I break this time down without losing the dictionary, namely what key is related to what polynomial?

I know if I only look at values the time would be reduced, but then I will not know the output would belong to which key from the association.

Comment: If you have 8 cores, and use `ParallelTable`, that would take less than 12 minutes. Is that too long?

Comment: I have 4 so presume it will take 24', is there any way to chunk the code down into easier-to-handle part?

Comment: For all of the polynomials you give, the maximum lies at the lower edge of your search interval. Maybe there's something generalizable here: maybe it's possible to exclude a large number of polynomials by just looking at the values (and derivatives) at the end points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would take less than 25 minutes with 4 cores.

```
LaunchKernels[];
maxlist = ParallelTable[
   MaxValue[{eq, 2/382 <= x <= 1}, x]
   , {eq, List @@ f}
  ];

Pick[
 Keys[f],
 Thread[Greater[maxlist, 1]]
]
```

---

My take on the answer by Carl Woll, which should bring you below 6 minutes.

```
trueFalseList = ParallelTable[
  UnsameQ[
   False,
   Quiet[
    Reduce[eq > 1 && 2/382 <= x <= 1, x]
    , Reduce::ratnz]
   ], {eq, List @@ f}]

Pick[
 Keys[f],
 trueFalseList
]
```

Comment: The second method is fabulously fast, thank you and Carl Woll.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) instead of [`MaxValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxValue). For instance, the "vanilla:veal" rational function is:

```
p = (353.073 x + 1137.02 x^2 + 2301.78 x^3 + 
 3771.09 x^4 + 5369.78 x^5 + 6302.43 x^6 + 6703.86 x^7 + 
 6518.57 x^8 + 5440.72 x^9 + 4612.02 x^10 + 3457.49 x^11 + 
 2654.9 x^12 + 2100.02 x^13 + 1521.13 x^14 + 1076.02 x^15 + 
 755.953 x^16 + 480.615 x^17 + 261.089 x^18 + 204.306 x^19 + 
 110.874 x^20 + 55.7565 x^21 + 28.2723 x^22 + 28.1937 x^23 + 
 19.6806 x^24 + 5.60733 x^25 + 3.72775 x^26 + 0.929319 x^27 + 
 1.8534 x^28 + 2.77225 x^29 + 0.921466 x^30 + 
 1.8377 x^31)/(354 x + 1143 x^2 + 2320 x^3 + 3811 x^4 + 
 5441 x^5 + 6403 x^6 + 6829 x^7 + 6658 x^8 + 5571 x^9 + 
 4737 x^10 + 3560 x^11 + 2741 x^12 + 2174 x^13 + 1579 x^14 + 
 1120 x^15 + 789 x^16 + 502 x^17 + 275 x^18 + 215 x^19 + 
 117 x^20 + 59 x^21 + 30 x^22 + 30 x^23 + 21 x^24 + 6 x^25 + 
 4 x^26 + x^27 + 2 x^28 + 3 x^29 + x^30 + 2 x^31)
```

Compare:

```
MaxValue[{p, 2/382 <= x <= 1}, x] //AbsoluteTiming
Quiet[Reduce[p > 1 && 2/382 <= x <= 1, x], Reduce::ratnz] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.133098, 0.976077}
>
> {0.041712, False}

Another example where the result isn't false:

```
MaxValue[{p+.5, 2/382 <= x <= 1}, x] //AbsoluteTiming
Quiet[Reduce[p+.5 > 1 && 2/382 <= x <= 1, x], Reduce::ratnz] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.128614, 1.47608}
>
> {0.041923, 0.0390256 < x <= 1.}

So, using [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) is about 3 times faster. Combine it with a [`ParallelTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTable) approach as in @rherman's answer.

Answer (score 5):

The following is not the exact filter that you want, but a simple prefilter that apparently is quite good at filtering the given example ;) The point is that this check is much cheaper than computing the maxima, so it can be used to filter out (hopefully) many rational functions from your list `f`, so that filtering the resulting list becomes less expensive.

Here is the code:

```
a = 2./382;
b = 1.;
picker =
    ParallelMap[
     With[{x = a + (b - a) z/(1 + z)},
       With[{p = Together[#]},
        Min[CoefficientList[Denominator[r] - Numerator[r], z]] < 0.
        ]
       ] &,
     Values[f]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

fpresieved = Pick[f, picker]
```

> 0.04817
>
> <||>

Here is the idea behind the method.

Let $r(x)$ be a rational function from your list `f`.
First, we apply the substitution `x = a + (b - a) z/(1 + z)`; The mapping $z \mapsto x$ maps the $[0,\infty]$ to the interval $[a,b]$.
Thus, $r = \frac{p}{q}$ is a rational function on the positive real axis for which we want to check whether

$$r(x) = \frac{p(z)}{q(z)} \leq 1 \quad \text{for all $z \geq 0$.}$$

This is equivalent to

$$q(z) - p(z) \geq 0  \quad \text{for all $z \geq 0$.}$$

A *sufficient* condition for this is that all coefficients of the polynomial $q(z) - p(z)$ are nonnegative. So a *necessary* condition for `r(x)` to be selected is that at least one coefficient of $q(z) - p(z)$ is negative. And precisely that is checked for in the code above.